# How can I float 1st div to left and the 2nd to the right?

Tags: css, html, updatepanel

I have a DIV with two update panels inside of them. The update panels render as divs but asp.net does not let me assign a class to a div. I can do this using jQuery by assigning css to the first child, then assigning different css to the 2nd or last child. Can I do this purely with css?

Something similar to this:

```
.outerdiv div
{
   width:45%;
}

/*float:left */
.outerdiv div(0)
{
   float:left;
}

/*float:right */
.outerdiv div(1)
{
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can wrap the Update Panel DIVs with another DIV...

```
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="outerdivleft">
    ... Update Panel Left ...
  </div>
  <div class="outerdivright">
    ... Update Panel Right ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't scale to more divs than 2, you can use:

```
.outerdiv div { float: right; }
.outerdiv div:first-child { float: left }
```

Comment: If you do this make sure you have a DOCTYPE declaration or this will not work in IE. http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that .outerdiv only contains those two div's, this should work in most modern web browsers:

```
.outerdiv div:first-child {float:left;}
.outerdiv div:last-child {float:right;}
```